# How to display and hide a div when particular button is clicked?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<button>good</button><br>   
<button>bad</button><br> 
<div class="new" style = "display: none;">booknow</div>
<div class="old">
    <a href="www.success.html">welcome.</a>
</div>
```

and the following JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {   /*button click event*/   
            $(".new").toggle();          /*new class calling */
        });       
    });
</script>
```

How can I toggle the visibility of the div(s) with class `new` whenever a button is clicked?

Comment: Can u write please which logic u want, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("button.good").click(function(){ 
      $(".new").toggle();
   });
   $("button.bad").click(function(){ 
      $(".old").toggle();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="good">Good</button><br> 
<button class="bad">Bad</button><br> 
 <div class="new">booknow</div>
<div class="old"><a href="www.success.html">welcome.</a></div>
```

Comment: @abdul It help you. try it.

Comment: @ abdul Yes I add both good and bad button click(). check it.

Comment: @ abdul if any doubt let me know.

Comment: i will select best answer for u ...wait

Comment: pls wait for 3 min ..i can't select it.